# How do I re-Load Fluid Sim Cache?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I baked a fluid Simulation and it saved the fluid cache above the blend file in a folder called: fluid_cache. But when I closed blender and reopened the project, I had to re-bake the simulation.

Is there a way to load the old cache files so I don't have to re-bake the simulation?

Comment: Hi, I just tried with 2.79rc2: I create a new default file, and saved it. Then used "quick fluid" on the default cube: it set the cache folder to "//cache_fluid" (that means a subfolder in the current file folder). Then I baked the fluid sim, and at the end, saved again the file. Then closed Blender, reopened last file, and the bake was already there, playable without needing to bake it again.... Also I tried to move both the .blend file and cache_fluid subfolder to another new folder. It worked again.

Comment: hmmm interesting. It didn't do this for me. I wonder if I have my output dir, set to the same folder as the blend file. I will check....

Comment: Yup that was exactly it. I had my Blend file and the Cache folder in two separate folders lol

Answer (score 1):

At least part of the answer to this question is:

Make sure that the .blend file you are opening is located in the same folder with the fluid_cache folder.

Comment: If this answer resolves your question (which I'm guessing it did since you added the answer after your comments back to @m.ardito) please click the 'Accept' button to accept it so the question is marked as accepted. You can accept your own answer and actually get a small amount of reputation for this.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Preferences' tab, go to 'File Paths' and set the path of the 'Render Cache' to (a folder) where your .blend files are stored. Then the cache should persist between loads.

Just make sure that you move the cache folder with the .blend files.