# How do I use a cached/baked smoke simulation with command line rendering?

Tags: rendering, baking, command-line

Under cache in the physics tab on the smoke domain, I have `Use Library Path` and `External` checked and a `Path` set in the path box. It says 26 frames found and works fine from rendering with the GUI.

When rendering from the command line, the smoke is not there. The command is:

```
./blender -b ../../Blender_Projects/Test33.blend -f 26 -o ../../Blender_Projects/Test_Renders/TestRender33.png
```

It seems that the command line isn't finding the cached/baked files. Do I need to pass the bake path as an argument? (Even though it's in the file already)?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for cloud rendering via command line, as for a local computer or render-farm, I don't know.

Change the cache baking location with the file path " // ". It should auto-name it if it doesn't accept a custom name.

Save the .blend file, bake the simulation and it will appear where you saved the .blend. Therefore blender will "look" in the same folder, a dedicated location.

[How do I re-Load Fluid Sim Cache?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89538/how-do-i-re-load-fluid-sim-cache#)